# Is it possible to use SendKeys for a specific application without SetForegroundWindow?

Tags: c#, sendkeys

While working on the main screen, I want to send a right click command to Firefox, which is opened on the second vertical screen. But I don't want Firefox to become active when I send commands. I tried this but it didn't work:

```
const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox");
    foreach (var proc in processes)
    {
        PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, (int)Keys.Right, 0);
        // I have to use SendKeys.SendWait for the messages to be processed.
        SendKeys.SendWait("{RIGHT}");
    }
}
```

And this works, but every time I send a command, Firefox becomes active. It doesn't work when I disable the `SetForegroundWindow` method.

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
private static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr ptr);
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var p = Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox").FirstOrDefault();
    if (p != null)
    {
        IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
        SetForegroundWindow(h);
        SendKeys.SendWait("{RIGHT}");
    }
}
```

Comment: "SetForegroundWindow" -> "Brings the thread that created the specified window into the foreground and activates the window" which you do NOT want. Also, where are you "disabling" the function exactly?

Comment: @SurajS - It doesn't work when I disable the 'SetForegroundWindow' method.

Comment: How do you "disable" a method exactly? You are clearly calling the method on the window handle

Comment: Like `//SetForegroundWindow(h);` Nothing else comes to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

A Click is a `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP`. Can you try calling the functions using the first method like so

```
 foreach (var proc in processes)
    {
        PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, (int)Keys.RButton, (IntPtr)0x001E0001);
        PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, (int)Keys.RButton, (IntPtr)0xC01E0001);
        // I have to use SendKeys.SendWait for the messages to be processed.
        SendKeys.SendWait("{RIGHT}");     //I dont believe you need this with the above approach
    }
```

You can also try sending the `WM_CONTEXTMENU` message if that is what you are after

I must also point out that `Keys.Right` is for the `Right` arrow key and not the right mouse click, you should use `Keys.RButton` instead

Here is the [List of KeyCodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#keystroke-message-flags) and more info on [KeyStrokes in win32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#keystroke-message-flags)

Comment: I have updated the answer, WM_KEYUP and WM_KEYDOWN require special flags set in LPARAM.

Comment: Is it possible to use `SendKeys.SendWait`. Because I did not manage to run your code.